# Why is shinymeta code modal dialog blank?

Tags: r, shiny, code-generation

When trying to display code modal in below example, clicking "show code" displays a blank window with no code output. metaRender and renderPlot functions appear to work as plot displays fine, just no code generation when clicking "show code", simply a blank window appears instead of the expected output `hist(diamonds$carat)`. Has anyone observed this behavior when using shinymeta, or have any guidance on how to further debug?

```
library(shiny)
library(shinymeta)
library(ggplot2)
library(shinyAce)

ui <- fluidPage(
    outputCodeButton(plotOutput("p1"))
)


server <- function(input, output) {

    output$p1 <- metaRender(renderPlot, {
        hist(diamonds$carat)
    })


observeEvent(input$p1_output_code, {
    code <- expandChain(output$p1())
    displayCodeModal(code)
})    

}
shinyApp(ui, server)
```

And here is some session info:

```
R version 3.6.1 (2019-07-05)
Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
Running under: Windows >= 8 x64 (build 9200)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252   
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C                          
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252    

attached base packages:
[1] stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base     

other attached packages:
[1] shinyAce_0.4.1 shinymeta_0.2.0          ggplot2_3.3.0           shiny_1.4.0.9002
```

Comment: It works fine for me, try to update the `shiny` package

Comment: Shiny is updated, it is indeed the most recent version that's causing this behavior.

Comment: My only difference with your `sessionInfo` is that I have shiny 1.4.0.2

Comment: Yes, 1.4.0.9 is more current than 1.4.0.2 which is why when I went back to 1.4.0 things worked again.

Answer (score 0):

I believe the issue lies with the most recent version of Shiny - shiny_1.4.0.9002

When clicking "show code" I receive an error in the R console that states: "The R.cache package needs to create a directory that will hold cache files." Then a Y/n prompt to create the R.cache directory.  Entering "Y" will eliminate the error message next time the Shiny app is run, but a blank code modal appears when clicking "show code"

Installing shiny_1.4.0 appears to resolve things. No R.cache error message and code generation works as expected. I'm not sure what's changed in shiny_1.4.0.9002 but it appears to be breaking the code modal dialog.